# Excel VBA: Iteration Code, But Need 2nd or 3rd Instance of DIV Class

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, worked up from my earlier question which was answered Tim Williams. However, a few minutes after it was working I figured out something else that was a new requirement and wasn't posed with the original question. Given the code below and the following HTML structure how can I modify the code to extract data from the second or even third DIV using the same "right-header" class? The child DIVs have no class or ID, they are just wrappers.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="right-header">
 <div>Entry 1</div>
 <div>Entry 2</div>
 <div>Entry 3</div>
 <div>Entry 4</div>
 <div>Entry 5</div>
 <div>Entry 6</div>
</div>

 <div class="right-header">
 <div>Entry 1</div>
 <div>Entry 2</div>
 <div>Entry 3</div>
 <div>Entry 4</div>
 <div>Entry 5</div>
 <div>Entry 6</div>
</div>

<div class="right-header">
 <div>Entry 1</div>
 <div>Entry 2</div>
 <div>Entry 3</div>
 <div>Entry 4</div>
 <div>Entry 5</div>
 <div>Entry 6</div>
</div>
```

Here is the modified VBA from Tim Williams:

```
Sub extract()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim topDiv, div, childDivs, tc As String, cntr

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\john\Documents\Test.html"

' Wait while IE loading
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set topDiv = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("right-header")(0)

Set childDivs = topDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")

cntr = 2

For Each div In childDivs
    tc = Trim(div.textContent)
    If tc <> "" Then
        Select Case Right(tc, 1)
            Case "<div>"
                'not sure whether you should be seeing HTML in textcontent...?
                Range("B" & cntr) = CStr(tc)
            Case "%"
                Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
                cntr = cntr + 1
            Case 0
                Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
            Case Else
                Range("A" & cntr).Value = tc
        End Select
    End If
    cntr = cntr + 1
Next div

Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = topDiv.textContent

'Cleanup
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone, sorry for the additional question so close to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just put it in a loop if the number of divs are known

```
    Sub extract()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim topDiv, div, childDivs, tc As String, cntr

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 "C:\Nitesh\test.html"

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    For i = 0 To 2

        Set topDiv = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("right-header")(i)

        Set childDivs = topDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")

        cntr = 2

        For Each div In childDivs
            tc = Trim(div.textContent)
            If tc <> "" Then
                Select Case Right(tc, 1)
                    Case "<div>"
                        'not sure whether you should be seeing HTML in textcontent...?
                        Range("B" & cntr).Offset(0, i) = CStr(tc)
                    Case "%"
                        Range("C" & cntr).Offset(0, i).Value = tc
                        cntr = cntr + 1
                    Case 0
                        Range("C" & cntr).Offset(0, i).Value = tc
                    Case Else
                        Range("A" & cntr).Offset(0, i).Value = tc
                End Select
            End If
            cntr = cntr + 1
        Next div

    Next i

End Sub
```

and offset all your outputs by `i` to get the results in a new column.

[image: Get Divs]

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I put the "next I" line directly after the "Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = topDiv.textContent" and it seems to be dropping each successive div one after another in column "B", not C, D, E, etc. Should the "next I" line be placed somewhere other than where I put it? Thank you!

Comment: Although you accepted the answer(Thanks), i have put the full code and the results image. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub extract()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim topDivs, topDiv, div, childDivs, tc As String, cntr

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\john\Documents\Test.html"

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    cntr = 2

    'get all the top-level divs
    Set topDivs = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("right-header")

    'loop over the top-level divs
    For Each topDiv In topDivs

        'get child divs for this top-level div
        Set childDivs = topDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")

        For Each div In childDivs
            tc = Trim(div.textContent)
            If tc <> "" Then
                Select Case Right(tc, 1)
                    Case "<div>"
                        'not sure whether you should be seeing HTML in textcontent...?
                        Range("B" & cntr) = CStr(tc)
                    Case "%"
                        Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
                        cntr = cntr + 1
                    Case 0
                        Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
                    Case Else
                        Range("A" & cntr).Value = tc
                End Select
            End If
            cntr = cntr + 1
        Next div

    Next topDiv

    'Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = topDiv.textContent

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```